# Angular Material mat-button does not seem to work inside of *NgFor when working with an array of hardcoded objects

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I am been working in Angular for a few years and have came across something odd. I am not sure if this is a weird Angular issue with the version or somehow I just never came across this specific issue. I also tried this in a new Angular application for my own sanity and the issue seems to still persist.

Essentially I created a getter to return a hardcoded array of objects. Then I loop through the objects in the template to show their data as well as create a button for each item. Now when I do not use **MatButtonModule** `mat-button` the button will work as expected. However when I use `mat-button` the button no longer fires.

Now there are some cases where I can get `mat-button` to work. If instead of using a getter I call `locationsTest`  in the template the buttons will work. The getter also works if I return the variable `locationsTest` . Also if I return an array of string or an array of integers from the getter the `mat-button` will work and the buttons will fire on click. It seems it only happens with a getter returning a hardcoded array of objects.

Why would this be happening? Below is the use case that fails and I am unsure why this would be occurring. When testing below ensure to import **MatButtonModule** after installing the @angular/material package or else `mat-button` does nothing.

component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let location of locations">
  <div>
    <h4>{{ location.name }}</h4>
    <p>{{ location.address }}</p>
    <p>{{ location.city }} </p>
  </div>
</div>

<button mat-button (click)="GoToLocation()">
  Go To Location
</button>
```

component.ts

```
let locationsTest = [
    {
      name: "Walmart",
      address: "123 Mcdougal Street W",
      city: "Toronto"
    },
    {
     name: "Barber Shop",
     address: "22 cat Street",
     city: "Toronto"
   }
 ];

public get locations(): any {
  return [
    {
      name: "Walmart",
      address: "123 Mcdougal Street W",
      city: "Toronto"
    },
    {
     name: "Barber Shop",
     address: "22 cat Street",
     city: "Toronto"
   }
 ];
}

public GoToLocation(): void {
  console.log('Going to Location');
}
```

Comment: It works fine https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pmgmyl

Comment: You are not importing MatButtonModule, so mat-button does nothing in your code

Comment: You have to install @angular/material

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue can be caused by multiple different reasons. I would suggest trying the following as a checklist as these always end up being the reasons for me:

1. Is Angular Material Installed?

   I find sometimes we forget to install Angular material and the error is being hidden because of a different error that has yet to be discovered.
2. Are the modules imported? In this case MatbuttonModule

   This is another common one I have came across where we forgot to import the module and therefor Angular does not know what the component or directive is. In this case potentially Angular does not know what the `mat-button` directive is but the error is silent because of a different error.
3. (Most common) You used a getter returning a value that updates itself!

   This is my most common issue I find when this doesn't work. It is very common when we develop to return **mock** data. However if you are creating an Observable or BehaviorSubject within a getter or setting a value in general you may be causing Angular to keep triggering lifecycle methods. This would in turn prevent angular functionality from firing as Angular is busy constantly updating.

   Example:

   ```
   //TS File: 
   public get userNames(): Observable<Array<string>> {
     public names = new BehaviorSubject<Array<any>>(null);

     let mockNames = [
       'L1ghtk3ira',
       'Thor4Life',
       'OverwatchKing'
     ];

     names.next(mockNames)

     return names.asObservable();
   }

   /html file
   <ng-container *ngIf="userNames | async as listOfUserNames;'>
     <p *ngFor="let userName of listOfUserNames">
       {{ userName  }}
     </p>
   </ng-container>
   ```

   This code above seems harmless however what is truly happening when we use this in a template. When our `*ngIf` (or even if we did async straight in out `*ngFor` loop) angular gets the data and during that time sets new data. Angular detects this and decides to perform another change detection when the current change detection has finished. When the next change detection happen this issue repeats itself. So even though you see no change on the screen as the data is the same it creates a neverending loop of change detection. Therefor anything inside the for loop such as `(click)` events can never be fired as Angular is constantly checking and updating itself.

   There are two ways to fix this. The fist is simple, we set the value outside of the getter in any way, in my example I chose to just set it as the initial value. change the past TS file to the following:

   ```
   public names = new BehaviorSubject<Array<any>>(
     [
       'L1ghtk3ira',
       'Thor4Life',
       'OverwatchKing'
     ]
   );

   public get userNames(): Observable<Array<string>> {
     return names.asObservable();
   }
   ```

A good rule of thumb to remember with Angular is if you are using a getter in a template never set a value within the getter as it will trigger an endless sea of change detection. Though this should go without saying in general, though mistakes happen.